# Generation Error

Tags: php, propel

When executing: **propel-gen om** I receive the following error `propel-gen: 22: propel-gen: Bad substitution`.

I've tried upgrading and downgrading Propel in an effort to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can we see your schema? And what table/column it seems to be failing on? Have you tried a super-simple schema to eliminate potential errors in yours?

Comment: line 22 on propel-gen is     SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"

Comment: My schema <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<database name="project" defaultIdMethod="native">
  <table name="form" phpName="Form" idMethod="native">
    <column name="ID" phpName="adminuserID" type="INTEGER" size="10" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
    <column name="Name" phpName="adminuserEmail" type="VARCHAR" size="50" required="true"/>
    <column name="FormAPIID" phpName="adminuserPassword" type="INTEGER" size="10" required="true"/>
  </table>
</database>

Comment: I don't get an error with this schema using Propel 1.6.7. Can we see your `build.properties` file?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I was using SH to run the script instead of BASH.